# d3.js & NVD3 axisLabel with a £ (pound) symbol

Tags: javascript, d3.js, symbols, nvd3.js

I'm trying to add a pound symbol to an NVD3 axis label.

The following <s>doesn't</s> does work:

```
chart.yAxis.axisLabel('£')
```

This doesn't

```
chart.yAxis.axisLabel('&pound;')
```

Not sure if there's a simple solution or whether this is an NVD3 or d3 limitation.

I guess I will implement some manual hack to fix it (eg. not just draw the axis label with NVD3), but not sure how to proceed?

- d3 version: **3.1.5**
- nvd3 version: **1.1.15b**

---

**Update:** Turned out problem was the editor (ace) I was using was removing the £ symbol, nothing to do with d3 or nvd3.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
chart.yAxis.tickFormat(function(d) {
    var format = d3.format(",d");
    return '£ ' + format(d)
});
```

OR

```
chart.yAxis.tickFormat(function(d) {
    return '£ ' + d
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks that's the format of the numbers, not the label, as you can see above turns out I had an seperate problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
chart.yAxis.tickFormat = function(d) {
    //Retuns currency formatted string with pound sign 
    // d3.format('c')(163) --> To Convert unicode
    return d3.format('c')(163) + ' ' + d3.format(',.2f')(d);
}
```